# Magento override abstract block

Tags: magento, overriding, block, abstract, mage

I need to override an abstract Block in Magento : app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Options/Abstract.php

I need to add a function to this class similar as getOptionValues for a specific product type.

I tried to override by adding the same structure (folder creations and copy the Abstract.php file) in app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Options/Abstract.php, but it seems not working.

Anyone can help me ?
Am I missing something ?
Do I need to create app/etc/modules XML or the app/code/local/Mage/Eav/etc XML ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to override the `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Options/Abstract.php` 

abstract class, you  need to place the file as: `app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/Options/Abstract.php`
which means your local pool path for Abstract.php is correct.

The only thing that i doubt why it's not loading is: 
may be Compiler is enabled for your store(be sure to check from `System > Tools > Compilation` > Status should be Disabled).

Additionally check your log files(var/log/*.log) if there are any errors.
 
I would refer the following article  for configuring your magento for development / debug mode:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/

Hope this helps a bit.
Regards

Comment: Okay I was totally wrong about the class ...
It was another file I needed to edit, I guess this is why my overrride didn't work ;)
Thank you for your help.